# Kafka - How to change the configured voter set?

Tags: apache-kafka

I removed a Kafka broker from my Kafka cluster and this has caused the other brokers to fail to restart.

The following error message is from `server.log`.

```
ERROR [SharedServer id=1] Got exception while starting SharedServer (kafka.server.SharedServer)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configured voter set: [1, 3] is different from the voter set
read from the state file: [1, 2, 3]. Check if the quorum configuration is up to date, or wipe out the
local state file if necessary
```

I removed Kafka Broker with id=2, so it makes sense that this error is shown. What I don't understand is:

- where is the "local state file"? what file is this error message referring to?
- how do I fix this error? should I delete this state file?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be as simple as editing the [quorum-state file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-595%3A+A+Raft+Protocol+for+the+Metadata+Quorum#KIP595:ARaftProtocolfortheMetadataQuorum-QuorumState).

```
sudo vim /opt/kafka/logs/kraft-combined-logs/__cluster_metadata-0/quorum-state
```

- Edit as necessary

```
sudo systemctl restart kafka
```

The cluster isn't quite back online yet, I would guess it needs some time to synchronize

Edit:

Even after the sync finished (watch `server.log`) this error appears when trying to connect with Conduktor:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 369296129 larger than 104857600)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:94)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:1107)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:1011)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```